# Force Psych to read YAML map as object of given class

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml

I have a class `Foo` that is supposed to be serialized to a text file in most human-friendly way possible, I use Ruby's default YAML(Psych) with custom `encode_with`. My question is: if I remove `!ruby/object:Foo` like so:

```
def encode_with coder
  coder.tag = nil
  ...
end
```

can I somehow still force Psych to load a map as object of class `Foo`(using its `init_with`). Ideally, I'd like to remove `---` document mark as well.

Of course, this is easy to solve with `gsub`, but I wonder if there is some Psych solution for this. Unfortunately, Psych isn't the best documented of gems.

Comment: How would you distinguish between maps that should be loaded normally, and ones that have to be read as Foo? Or all all maps from this file going to be loaded as Foo?

Comment: @Anthon Top-level map (i.e. whole file) is supposed to be load as `Foo`. Any sub-maps as normal `Hash`es

Comment: Then you should just convert the top level hash to your `Foo` class after loading, by creating the keys of as attributes and the values as the attribute value.

Comment: @Anthon This level of implementation details exposure is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Psych is not going to guess itself what needs to be done, so some level of implementation detail has to be in your program. From my experience with YAML parsers (but not with Psych so it might be different), you don't have that level of control what a mapping is rendered as depending on its nesting depth, while it is parsing. So you have to do something afterward (as suggested), or before. The latter you could e.g do by inserting the `!ruby/object:Foo` programmatically before you hand the whole thing to Psych.

Comment: @Anthon Psych has nice build-in way to allow custom yaml encoding for a class, that includes easy way to remove `!ruby/object:Foo` tag, so I _suspect_ that it has a way to properly read object when yaml lacks it, it just isn't easy to find it because of its poor doc. Right now I deal with it using `gsub`, but I'm still digging.

Comment: Can you make your object's constructor so that it accepts a `hash`/`array` that is generated by `Psych`? So to say `MyObject.new(JSON.parse(my_file_name))` ? Undocumented things tend to change with gem updates, I'd try to find an approach that gives me more control over what happens

Comment: Currently I do just that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide your own `Handler` to Psych:

```
class MyHandler < Psych::Handlers::DocumentStream
  def start_mapping(anchor, tag, implicit, style)
    unless @__root
      tag = "!ruby/hash:MyHash"
      @__root = true
    end
    super anchor, tag, implicit, style
  end
end

class MyHash < Hash
end

def my_parse(yaml)
  parser = Psych::Parser.new(MyHandler.new{|node| return node})
  parser.parse yaml
  false
end

# {a: 1, b: {c: 2, d: 3}, c: [1,2,3]}.to_yaml
str = "---\n:a: 1\n:b:\n  :c: 2\n  :d: 3\n:c:\n- 1\n- 2\n- 3\n"

result = my_parse(str).to_ruby
puts result.class # => MyHash
```

A bit of documentation. `my_parse` is just a re-implementation of Psych [default parse method](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych.rb#L323). Instead of [default handler](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych.rb#L373) I use `MyHandler` here.

`MyHandler`'s `start_mapping` method overrides `TreeBuilder`'s [default implementation](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych/tree_builder.rb#L27). This is a callback which is called when parser bumps into Map in YAML, and document root *is* a Map. So you just need to swap the tag for the root element (and don't bother with everything else – that's why I use `@__root` variable to skip further modifications).