# How to use YAML.load with handlers

Tags: ruby, yaml

```
irb(main):001:0> a="run: yes"
 => "run: yes"
 irb(main):002:0> require 'yaml'
 => true
 irb(main):003:0> YAML.load a
 => {"run"=>true}
 irb(main):004:0> YAML.load(a, handlers => {'bool#yes' = identity})
 SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting =>
 YAML.load(a, handlers => {'bool#yes' = identity})
                                      ^
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>
```

I want the yaml val is yes and i google find the handler will help.
But seems i do not use correct syntax.
I try to search related docs but fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems with the listed code are

- that `handlers` isn't defined anywhere, you likely wanted `:handlers`
- that `identity` isn't defined anywhere, maybe wanted `:identity` that
- you are missing a `>` on your hash rocket (`=>`).

So to get this code to run it should (likely) look like

```
YAML.load("run: yes", :handlers => {'bool#yes' => :identity})
```

However, so far as I know the second parameter to [`YAML.load`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load) is a filename.

If you are able to change the input YAML, simply quoting the value "yes" will cause it come through as a string

```
YAML.load("a: 'yes'")
# => {"a"=>"yes"}
```

If you require the un-quoted string 'yes' in the YAML to be treated as `'yes'`, not `true` in ruby after parsing. I cobbled this together (with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104842/force-psych-to-read-yaml-map-as-object-of-given-class)), using [Psych::Handler](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Handler.html) and [Pysch::Parser](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Parser.html). Though I'm not sure if there's another easier/better way to do this without having to hack this all together like this.

```
require 'yaml'

class MyHandler < Psych::Handlers::DocumentStream
  def scalar(value, anchor, tag, plain, quoted, style)
    if value == 'yes'
      super(value, anchor, tag, plain, true, style)
    else
      super(value, anchor, tag, plain, quoted, style)
    end
  end
end

def my_parse(yaml)
  parser = Psych::Parser.new(MyHandler.new{|node| return node})
  parser.parse yaml

  false
end

my_parse("a: yes").to_ruby
# => {"a"=>"yes"}
my_parse("a: 'yes'").to_ruby
# => {"a"=>"yes"}
my_parse("a: no").to_ruby
# => {"a"=>false}
```

Sidenote in the console ([and the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_4/lib/yaml.rb#L14)):

```
YAML
# => Psych
```